# Como aplicar teste unitários quando a classe principal é uma interface?

Tags: java, junit

Eu tenho esse método na minha classe Beginning

```
@Override
public void question() {
    String question = String.format(TEXT_OF_A_QUESTION, this.namePlate);
    int answer = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, question, "Question", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);

    if (Integer.valueOf(answer).equals(JOptionPane.YES_OPTION)) {
        this.positive.positiveAnswer();
    } else {
        this.negative.negativeAnswer(this);
    }
}
```

Como faço para criar um teste unitário para testar esse método?
Estou tento problemas porque meu model é uma interface como vocês podem ver abaixo;

```
package com.test.wladimir.gamergourmet.model;

public interface Plate {

    String namePlate();

    void question();

    void questionLevel(String positiveAnswer, String negativeAnswer);

    void positiveAnswer();

    void negativeAnswer(Plate plate);
}
```

Essa é minha [APLICAÇÃO](https://github.com/wladyband/testGamer/tree/master/src/main/java/com/test/wladimir/gamergourmet)

Esse foi minha tentativa;

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.Silent.class)
public class BeginningTest {

    private static final String TEXT_OF_A_QUESTION = "O prato que você pensou é %s?";
    private static String namePlate = "torta";

    private Plate positive;
    private Plate negative;

    @Mock
    private Beginning beginningController;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        beginningController = new Beginning(namePlate);
    }

    @Test
    public void testQuestion() {

        String question = String.format(TEXT_OF_A_QUESTION, this.namePlate);
        assertThat(question, notNullValue());

    }
```

Mas não sei se estar certo!

Comment: Fazer mocks com interface é mais fácil do que com classes. Use os métodos do Mockito para gerenciar a criação da instância da interface, evite criar na mão (exceto se seu objetivo é rodar o teste _sem_ o Mockito)

Answer (score 1):

A primeira coisa a ser entendida é saber **o que você deseja testar**.

No seu código, dá para testar os seguintes itens:

- Retorno do `String.format` no `TEXT_OF_A_QUESTION`
- Condição dentro do `if`

A [primeira dificuldade](http://shervinasgari.blogspot.com/2012/07/unit-testing-with-joptionpane.html) para testar seu código é este `JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog`. Você precisa, de alguma forma, colocar uma interface no lugar e mudar a implementação dela no teste.

Por exemplo:

```
class Beginning {

    private OptionPane optionPane = new DefaultOptionPane();

    private String namePlate;
    private Plate positive;
    private Plate negative;

    @Override
    public void question() {
        String question = String.format(TEXT_OF_A_QUESTION, this.namePlate);
        int answer = optionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, question, "Question", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);

        if (Integer.valueOf(answer).equals(JOptionPane.YES_OPTION)) {
            this.positive.positiveAnswer();
        } else {
            this.negative.negativeAnswer(this);
        }
    }

    public void setOptionPane(OptionPane o) { this.optionPane = o; }

}
```

E a implementação das 2 classes que irá precisar: uma com a implementação para a aplicação e outra para o teste unitário:

```
public class DefaultOptionPane implements OptionPane {

      public int showConfirmDialog(Component parentComponent, Object message, String title, int optionType, int messageType) {
         return JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(parentComponent,message,title,optionType,messageType);
      }
}

public class YesMockOptionPane implements OptionPane {

        @Override
 public int showConfirmDialog(Component parentComponent, Object message, String title, int optionType, int messageType) {
   return JOptionPane.YES_OPTION;
 }
}
```

Por padrão, seu código sempre usará o `DefaultOptionPane`, mas no seu teste você pode sobreescrevê-lo via o método o `setOptionPane`.

Depois, basicamente você vai precisar abusar dos métodos `verify` do mockito para entender se o `positive` ou `negative` é chamado, dependendo do retorno do `optionPane`. Mas seu código original instancia eles internamente, isto é ruim para mockar eles, pois também precisará expor eles. Você pode fazer isto criando métodos `set` para eles também, embora na prática o ideal era eles terem sido injetados via construtor, daí você pode usar o mesmo ponto de entrada para passar as classes mockadas.

Vou dar o exemplo usando `set` mesmo. Seria algo assim o seu teste:

```
@Test
public void test() throws Exception {

  OptionPane optionPane = mock(OptionPane.class);
  when(optionPane.showConfirmDialog(any(),any(),any(),any()).thenReturn(1); // 1 = Yes, eu acho...

  Pane negative = mock(Pane.class);
  Pane positive = mock(Pane.class);

  Beginning b = new Beginning ("lagosta");
  b.setOptionPane(optionPane);
  b.setNegative(negative);
  b.setPositive(positive);

  verify(positive, times(1)).positiveAnswer();
  verify(positive, times(0)).negativeAnswer(any());
}
```

Acredito que tenha conseguido pegar a ideia. O teste do `String.format` pode ser feita via mock, esperando o resultado desejado como ponto de entrada do método `showConfirmDialog`, algo assim:

```
when(optionPane.showConfirmDialog(any(),eq("O prato que você pensou é lagosta"),any(),any()).thenReturn(1);
```

Comment: Ficou bem explicado, porém na classe `DefaultOptionPane`  não existe a interface  `OptionPane`, estou usando o netbeans e pedi para ele pesquisar a dependência, e não encontrou, e pesquisei a dependência manualmente na internet, e também não encontrei, e também não importou a classe  `YesMockOptionPane`, porque diz que não existe. infelizmente não foi possível aplicar ao meu projeto por causa disso, meu repositório está na postagem, se puder dar uma olhada e mostrar como importar essas classes, vai ser muito importante para mim!

Comment: Olá! Creio que sua classe pode implementar qualquer interface. Você pode criar sua própria interface `OptionPane` e usar ela da maneira que coloquei. O `YesMockOptionPane` é uma classe que não existe, você também vai precisar criar ela (com o código que coloquei). O exemplo que dei acima foi para entender a ideia.

Comment: obrigado pela tentativa de me ajudar